# Making Swiper Slider's Transition Unidirectional

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, swipe

I have put together an image carousel with the help of **[Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/)**.

My carousel uses background images, bullets and vertical transition. I want this vertical transition to be *unidirectional*. In other words, the carousel transition direction should be *upwards*, regardless of the succession of the bullets clicked.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    auto: true,
    speed: 1000,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 9000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    controller: {
        inverse: true,
    }
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 265px;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    height: 265px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 265px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 620px;
    height: 265px;
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto !important;
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    margin: 0 !important;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    float: left;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url("https://grgs.ro/1/i/sprite.png") no-repeat -528px -502px;
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background-position: -528px -524px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/265/?gravity=east');">
            <img src="https://5.grgs.ro/images/b/c2/303073784cd9d0ee3aea0e039629ce5b.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/265/?gravity=south');">
            <img src="https://5.grgs.ro/images/b/c2/303073784cd9d0ee3aea0e039629ce5b.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/265/?gravity=west');">
            <img src="https://5.grgs.ro/images/b/c2/303073784cd9d0ee3aea0e039629ce5b.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I have been looking for information on the Swiper website, including the forum but could not find the way to make it *unidirectional*. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, pass the parameter `allowSlidePrev: false;`.

I have never used Swiper but and I have no way to test so i don't know if this will solve your bullets problem but in theory this will make it unidirectional .

Comment: It did not change anything. But Thanks!

Comment: this won't make it unidirectional, it will only disable the ability of user to navigate to previous slides, so user can only go to next slides by navigating through bullets, 
but the requirement was to be able to navigate to any slide with bullets and change the slide effect only one directional ( or unidirectional).

Example, user clicks on the previous slide, still the slide effect looks like as if it's sliding to the next element.